# Func Return Any Type

Tags: c#, func

I have the following property class:

```
class tbl_tax_type
{
    public int TAXT_ID { get; set; }
    public string BFNS_CODE { get; set; }
    public string TAXT_CODE { get; set; }
    public string TAXT_DESC { get; set; }
    public string ACCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
    public string CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LAST_MODIFIED_DATE { get; set; }
    public string LAST_MODIFIED_BY { get; set; }
    public string TAXT_STATUS { get; set; }
}
```

I use the method below to retrieve data from it:

```
private static List<T> SelectData<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> PredicateExp) where T : new()
{ 
    return FireCon().Table<T>().Where(PredicateExp).ToList();
}
```

By Usage (Code below selects rows from tbl_tax_type where BFNS_CODE is equal to 0605)

```
List<tbl_tax_type> TempList = SelectData<Tbl.tbl_tax_type>(taxtype => taxtype.BFNS_CODE == "0605")
```

Now I want to apply distinction on the selected data, so I came up to this method.

```
public static List<T> DistinctBy<T>(List<T> MyList, Func<T, __> SelectorExpr)
{
    return GenericList.Select(SelectorExpr).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

By Usage (Code below selects distinct TAXT_CODE)

```
DistinctBy(TempList, v => v.TAXT_CODE);
```

There's something missing, the TResult of the selector expression. I want it to return any type of data because the properties of tbl_tax_type had different data types. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static List<T> DistinctBy<T, S>(List<T> myList, Func<T, S> selectorExpr)
{
    return myList.ToLookup(selectorExpr).SelectMany(t => t.Take(1)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like ...

```
public static List<S> DistinctBy<T, S>(List<T> myList, Func<T, S> selectorExpr)
{
    return myList.Select(selectorExpr).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

?

Comment: He wants a distinct on S but an enumeration of T.

Comment: Hmm.. So get the list of all the T's which occur only once according to the selectorExpr?

Comment: Or what Enigmativity has answered which is arbitrarily take a single item of myList for each distinct value determined by selectorExpr.  Seems like odd functionality to want.

Comment: Going off the title of the article I'm guessing he wants a list of S not T