# Is there any way to pass a function reference in C# without specifying the result type?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5, func

I have a problem where I am trying to write a generic method that reads xml and writes the data to the database.

In this case that data was serialized by another copy of the program.

Before I add an item from the xml to the SqlParameter I need to run it through one of several different "Fixing" methods in the utilities file.

The particular method needed is something that needs to be passed in, so I have ended up passing it in as a string and using a switch structure to determine which method to call with reflection as a the default case.

I was wondering if there is any way to actually pass in the method reference without having to specify that it returned an int, string, bool, decimal, double, or DateTime.

I have tried using a Func but it requires a result type.

The new argument would probably look something like:
   `Tuple<string,Func<?>[] parameters`

These utility functions all take an object as a parameter.

I found a question that is almost what I am looking for except they don't have a list that can all be different:

[Func Return Any Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162198/func-return-any-type)

My current code:

```
private void SaveBundleToTable<T1, T2>
(
    string xmlData,
    string table,
    string storedProcedure,
    Tuple<string, string>[] parameters
)
    where T1 : DataSet, new()
    where T2 : DataRow
{
    T1 BundleData = new T1();
    BundleData.Clear();
    StringReader theReader = new StringReader(xmlDataset);
    BundleData.ReadXml(theReader);
    foreach (T2 item in BundleData.Tables[table].Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, [SQLConnection]);
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (var par in parameters)
        {
            var _param = getSqlParameter<T2>(item, par.First, par.Second);
            _cmd.Parameters.Add(_param);
        }
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Switch structure in a separate method:

```
private SqlParameter getSqlParameter<T>(T item, string columnName, string method) where T : DataRow
{
    switch (method)
    {
        case "FixString":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixString(item[columnName]));
        case "FixInt":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixInt(item[columnName]));
        case "FixBooleanToInt":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixBooleanToInt(item[columnName]));
        case "FixBoolean":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixBoolean(item[columnName]));
        case "FixFloat":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixFloat(item[columnName]));
        case "FixDouble":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixDouble(item[columnName]));
        case "FixDate":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixDate(item[columnName]));
        case "FixDateForZeroTime":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixDateForZeroTime(item[columnName]));
        case "FixDecimal":
            return new SqlParameter(columnName, util.FixDecimal(item[columnName]));
        default:
            try
            {
                Type thisType = util.GetType();
                MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(method);
                return new SqlParameter(columnName, theMethod.Invoke(this, new object[]{item[columnName]}));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown utility method: " + method,ex);
            }
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

I just tried using a parameter type of `Tuple<string,Func<object,dynamic>>` and it would not compile as it said it could not determine the type of `Tuple<string,?>`

As a note, This project is in .Net 3.5 so I implemented a local version of Tuple as discussed in this question:

[Equivalent of Tuple (.NET 4) for .NET Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120845/equivalent-of-tuple-net-4-for-net-framework-3-5)

Edit 2:

If I make a change to the generic method so I can pass an array of type `Tuple<string,Func<object,object>>` then when I try to call it I get a compile error on the decimal line:

```
new Tuple<string, Func<object,object>>[]
   {
        Tuple.New<string, Func<object,object>>("LAB_CODE",util.FixString),
        Tuple.New<string, Func<object,object>>("MORM_SELL",util.FixDecimal),
   ...
```

There is a larger error if I use `Tuple.New<string, Func<object,decimal>>`

Comment: The use of DataSets to read the xml is enforced by the program and can not be changed.

Comment: You can always use Delegate as your delegate type, which is the base type for delegate types generally and doesn't impose any signature. Since you're invoking via reflection anyway, I would expect that would work okay for you.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I would prefer not to use reflection here. Right now I am only using it as a fallback if the switch statement does not have the method in a defined case

Comment: I would also prefer not to have the switch structure at all. I only have it here because I can't invoke a method reference directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out a way to make the function passing work but it is way too verbose for my situation.

```cs
new Tuple<string, Func<object,object>>[]
{
    Tuple.New<string, Func<object,object>>("LAB_CODE",util.FixString),
    Tuple.New<string, Func<object,object>>("MORM_SELL",x => (object)util.FixDecimal(x)),
...
```

<s>Unless I find a more concise way to do this I think I will stick with my switch statement.</s>

Edit:

I added these functions to my static Tuple class:

```cs
public static Tuple<string, Func<object, object>> Util<T>(string first, Func<object, T> second)
{
    Func<object, object> method = getFunc<T>(second);
    var tuple = new Tuple<string, Func<object, object>>(first, method);
    return tuple;
}
private static Func<object,object> getFunc<T>(Func<object,T> method)
{
    return x => (object)method(x);
}
```

This lets me use this syntax to pass in the parameters:

```cs
new Tuple<string, Func<object,object>>[]
{
   Tuple.Util<string>("LAB_CODE",util.FixString),
   Tuple.Util<decimal>("MORM_SELL",util.FixDecimal),
...
```

These could be implemented in a extension function to use it with the .Net 4 Tuple class

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a util.Fix(Object o) function which returns the proper fix by determining the code through:

```
if (o is string) return util.FixString(o);
else if (o is int) return util.FixInt(o) ...
```

It's similar to what you have but it cleans up the management.  Your are stuck in that you are forced to perform some sort of if statement because you are doing different logic per data type.

For classes just create an interface which has the necessary method defined for the fix.

Comment: I did try something like this also. The problem with this is that there are some different "Fix" methods that return the same type:         `bool util.FixBoolean(object o)` & `bool util.FixBooleanToInt(object o)`. I am not sure what the different use case for these might be.

Comment: It might also have trouble on some of the different methods that use `float`, `decimal`, or `double` since I am not sure they would always be evaluated correctly.

Comment: As long as you return object, which SqlParameter takes you can always go deeper in your logic.  If (o is bool) { if (logic convert to int) util.FixBooleanToInt(o) else util.FixBoolean(o); }

Comment: These methods fall into groups of what datatype they handle but which method for a datatype handles a particular case is something that the type alone can't decide. For instance: if I have a DateTime, I might need to call either the regular FixDate or the FixDateForZeroTime method but they both need a DateTime object to work.

Comment: Well, there are business rules governing the conversion logic to create those method strings unless they are part of the original file.  Can you move that logic into a single function?

Comment: This utility class is legacy code and I don't really want to fiddle with it. I can't guess how many places it is used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply not use `Func<object, object>`? Even if the return type isn't an object, I am still able to compile it. Here is the example I tested on VS 2013:

```
public static string FixString(object data)
{
    return null;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataRow row = null;
    SqlParameter param = getSqlParameter(row, "Address", FixString);
}

private static SqlParameter getSqlParameter<T>(T item, string columnName, Func<object, object> method) where T : DataRow
{
    return new SqlParameter(columnName, method(item[columnName]));
}
```

Comment: If I pass in a method that returns an int or other primitive type it will not cast implicitly for some reason. also I am not passing in just a single function but an array of functions depending on what the SQL Parameter needs to be. Right now I am just passing the name of the function as a string as the 2nd part of the argument `Tuple<string, string>[] parameters` then mapping it to a function in a switch statement.